# closed SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying send email with phpmailer but it's not successfull,
network is ok
firewall is ok
openssl installed

```
Connection: opening to mail.mydomain.net:587, t=300, opt=array ()
Connection: opened
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 Exchange-01.mydomain.local Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 18 Mar 2021 10:43:11 +0330
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO 172.16.1.10
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-Exchange-01.mydomain.local Hello [172.16.1.10]250-SIZE 37748736250-PIPELINING250-DSN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-STARTTLS250-AUTH GSSAPI NTLM250-8BITMIME250-BINARYMIME250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SERVER -> CLIENT:
SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:
Connection: closed
SMTP connect() failed.
```

Comment: You need to post your code, how else can we figure out what you're doing wrong?

Comment: Not necessarily the problem, but it looks like you're using an old version of PHPMailer. [Upgrade](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: Thanks , Upgrade phpmailer solved my problem